# Sqoop export fails with Mysql

Tags: mysql, sqoop

While executing Sqoop Export jobs in Mysql, I'm facing following exception:

```
No columns to generate for ClassWriter
Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3306;"'.
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: show your table structure, sqoop command

Comment: user_id  username  password  email

Comment: sqoop export --connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books" --username root --password root --table users2 --export-dir /harini/users1/ --input-fields-terminated-by ","

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to export the data from HDFS to your MySQL table then you can use below syntax:

```
sqoop export \
    --connect jdbc:mysql://<HOST_NAME (or) IP_ADDRESS>:<MySQL_PORT_NO>/<DATABASE_NAME> \
    --username <DB_USER_NAME> \
    --password <DB_PASSWORD> \
    --table <YOUR_TABLE_NAME> \
    --export-dir <HDFS_PATH_FROM_WHERE_YOU_WANT_TO_EXPORT_DATA>
```

If I want to export the data from `/mysql/user/` which is located in HDFS to MySQL user table then the command will be as follows:

```
sqoop export \
    --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test \
    --username hadoopuser \
    --password **** \
    --table user \
    --export-dir /mysql/user/
```

Comment: sqoop export \
    --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books \
    --username root \
    --password **** \
    --table users \
    --export-dir /result/ this the command I have used. but the records could not be retrieve.

Comment: do you see any exception or any message stating the problem?? do you have data files in your hdfs path: **/result/** ??

Comment: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
This the error message I got it. Yes I have my data file in that specified path.

Comment: update your question with complete details that you have provided along with complete error message and also the table create structure and sample data from your hdfs